# Disable a specific date in full calender

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I am using full calender as a calender datepicker, and I am facing a problem. I want to disable some dates from clicking (dates in red colour).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: '<?php echo $today; ?>',
    selectable: true,
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
      $('input[type="text"]').val(date.format());
      //alert('Date:' + date.format());
    },
    editable: true,
    height: 400,
    eventLimit: true,
    events: [
      <?php foreach($lead as $l){?>
      {
        title: '<?php echo $l['ids']; ?>',
        start: '<?php echo $l['followup_date']; ?>',
        <?php if($l['ids'] >= $followuplimit) {?>
          backgroundColor    : '#FF0000',
          borderColor    : '#FF0000'
        <?php } else { ?>
          backgroundColor    : '#008C1F',
          borderColor    : '#008C1F'
        <?php } ?>
      },
      <?php } ?>
    ]
  });
});
```

Comment: are you using this "dayClick" to determine a day for creating an event on the calendar? If so, don't. Use the "select" callback as recommended by fullCalendar's docs. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/. Then you can use some combination of https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectConstraint/ or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectAllow/ to more easily implement rules about what periods of time can be selected, or not selected. There are quite a few previous answers on SO relating to that as well, if you search.

Comment: Oh I forgot also, that's a crazy way to create the event data. There is absolutely no need to build JSON by hand like that, it's potentially very error-prone and also difficult to read. Just use `json_encode()` instead

Comment: I formatted the code in a nicer way, including the bottom `})` that was off by a few spaces. Please also explain what you mean by "I want to disable some dates from clicking..." - do you mean you want to disable the red calendar from being clicked?

Comment: yes @ Blundering Philosopher

Answer (score 0):

You can disable date by adding `disabled` class to that cell.

**Logic :** Just have array of dates you want to disable and check if `date` variable is present in your date arra and if true add disable class.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    dayRender: function(date, cell){
        if (date > maxDate){
            $(cell).addClass('disabled');
        }
    }
    ...
});
```